# How to fetch NumberLong record in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a field in my document as

```
 "p_id" : NumberLong(2328703838)
```

I tried as below to fetch it

```
spec.find({p_id: id})
```

Where my id is 2328703838... but I am unable to fetch record even when data exists .Can anyone suggest help .Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`mongoose-long`](https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-long) to have Number Long support in mongoose.

Define your data type as `SchemaTypes.Long` and create a Long object with `Long.fromString("2328703838")` :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);

var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
var Long = mongoose.Types.Long;

var SpecSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    p_id: SchemaTypes.Long
});

var Spec = mongoose.model('Spec', SpecSchema);

var db = mongoose.connect('localhost', 'testDB');

var id = Long.fromString("2328703838");

Spec.find({ p_id: id }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand why they have to create a separate npm package **for each data type**. `NumberInt` and `NumberLong` are MongoDB built-in supported types, why not support them in `mongoose` proper?

Comment: How do you use the `mongoose-long` plugin with es6?

Comment: @lomse Try https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-long :)